# c++ What is wrong with my reheapification process in a max heap?

Tags: heapsort

This is my first stackexchange post, so please be gentle :-)  I am an undergraduate student taking data structures using c++.  Here is the header file we were given to implement (not allowed to use stl's heap class, but we can use its vector class):

```
template <typename T>
class heap
{
public:
    heap();
    // postcondition: empty heap has been created
    unsigned int size() const;
    // postcondition: number of elements in a heap has been returned
    bool is_empty() const;
    // postcondition: returned whether the heap is empty
    void insert (const T& item);
    // postcondition: item has been added
    void remove();
    // precondition: heap is not empty
    // postcondition: largest item has been removed from the heap
    T max() const;
    // precondition: heap is not empty
    // postcondition: copy of largest element in the heap has been returned
    T& max();
    // precondition: heap is not empty
    // postcondition: access to largest element in the heap has been returned

private:    
    std::vector<T> v;
    unsigned int max_child (unsigned int index) const;
    // precondition: element at index has children
    // postcondition: index of the larger child has been returned
    // if there is only 1 child - index of that child has been returned
};
```

I added this helper member function (in the private section)

```
//template <typename T>
void swap_up(const T& item, std::vector<int> v);
```

Here is my implementation of the insert function:

```
template <typename T>
void heap<T>::insert (const T& item)
// postcondition: item has been added
{
    v.push_back(item);
    if(v.size() > 1){
        swap_up(item, v);
    }
}
```

I know I shouldn't call the swap_up function if everything is already in order, but I'm not concerned about that right now.  I'm concerned with what's happening inside that function.  Here is my swap_up function:

```
template <typename T>
void heap<T>::swap_up(const T& item, std::vector<int> v){

    unsigned int index = v.size()-1;
    unsigned int parent_index = (index-1)/2;
    //unsigned int value;
    T value;

    while(item > v[parent_index]){

        //if(item > v[parent_index]){
            value = v[parent_index];
            v[parent_index] = item;
            v[index] = value;
        //}

        if(parent_index > 0){
            index = parent_index;
            parent_index = (index-1)/2;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "heap.h"
//#include "priority_queue.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    heap<int> h1;
    h1.insert(40);
    h1.insert(50);
    h1.insert(60);
    h1.insert(70);
    h1.insert(80);

    int max = h1.max();
    cout << "The max is " << max << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code the max is always 40.  I don't understand why, as I think my algorithm for moving from the end of the balanced heap until the appropriate stopping point is pretty solid.  Am I missing something here?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see my problem.  Every time I insert I do so into a new vector.  This would explain why the original vector always shows the first value as the largest - it never receives another value!  I want to change my code to still utilize my swap_up() function by accessing the private vector variable in heap.h, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do so.